# REST API springboot cannot get the Polymer iron ajax call

Tags: ajax, polymer

I am trying to send data from the front-end to the back-end.
In Polymer I have

```
<paper-radio-group selected="{{radioSelected}}">
  <paper-radio-button name="one">one</paper-radio-button>
  <paper-radio-button name="two">two</paper-radio-button>
</paper-radio-group>
```

in the JavaScript:

```
radioSelected: {
  observer: '_onSourceChanged'
},

_onSourceChanged: function (newValue, oldValue) {
  console.log('New value is ' + newValue);
}
```

How should I construct an ajax call to connect with the backend?
Note that only the `newValue` is needed for the backend.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the iron-ajax component, is very easy to use.

https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-ajax

This code goes in the html container.

```
<iron-ajax
id="myRequestId"
url="http://myurl.com"
method="POST"
content-type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"></iron-ajax>
```

This goes in any script function where you want to fire the post request.

```
this.$.myRequestId.body = JSON.stringify(myBodyParams);
this.$.myRequestId.generateRequest();
```